# R integral2 function not accepting xmax argument

Tags: r

I am trying to evaluate the following double integral numerically using integral2 function from R pracma package. For those who are interested in the context, it is related to the porject Euler problem "Pythagorean Ant". The following is a code snippet I have tried:

```
library(pracma)

f <- function(x, y) (2*pi - pi/2 - atan((40-y)/x) - atan((30-x)/y))/(2*pi)

xmin <- 0

xmax <- function(y) (30 - 0.75*y)

ymin <- 0

ymax <- 40

prob_integral <- integral2(f, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
```

It returns the following error message:

> ```
> > Error in integral2(f, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax) :    is.numeric(xmax) is
> > not TRUE
> ```

I have tried their example code and it works.

```
f <- function(x, y) sqrt(1 -x^2 - y^2)

xmin <- 0; xmax <- 1

ymin <- 0; ymax <- function(x) sqrt(1 - x^2)

I <- integral2(f, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
```

> `I$Q                             # 0.5236076 - pi/6 => 8.800354e-06`

I am wondering if my code does not work due to some points not having evaluation with the arctan function inside the integral. e.g. (0,40), (30,0). If that is the case, what is the alternative solution I can use?

Thanks for your help!

Brian

Comment: The error seems fairly clear - `xmax` is not numeric. You define `xmax <- function(y) (30 - 0.75*y)`, so `xmax` is a function. `integral2` wants `xmax` to be a number, not a function. The example works fine because it uses `xmax <- 1`, and `1` is a number, not a function.

Comment: As documented in the help of `integral2`. Only `ymin` and `ymax` may be functions of `x`. That is why your first example gives an error and the second does not.

Comment: Your first example also has xmin=0 and xmax at ymax also 0. Voting to close as typo. If you restate teh question more clearly an answer might be possible, but at the moment appears impossible to address.

Comment: Thanks for all of your comments. I think the key here is xmin and xmax can't be expressed in terms of functions. Another thing is when we write the boundaries in functions, they are not depending on another min or max of another boundary. It actually depends on the variable being integrated with respect to. Take the official example, ymax <- function(x) sqrt(1 - x^2), we can't say ymax = 0 when xmax = 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed things a little and it worked as expected. I think what the function does is to integrate f(x,y) with respect to y from ymin = 0 to ymax = 40*(30-x)/30 first. This will give a new function (say g(x)) that depends only on x. Then, it integrates g(x) with respect to x from 0 to 30 to give the value. Since only y boundaries can be expressed in terms of functions, it must have done the inner integration with respect to y first. Please let me know if this makes sense. Thanks!

```
library(pracma)

f <- function(x, y) (2*pi - pi/2 - atan((40-y)/x) - atan((30-x)/y))/(2*pi)
xmin <- 0;
xmax <- 30;
ymin <- 0;
ymax <- function(x) 40*(30-x)/30;

prob_integral <- integral2(f, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
```